# Rows to columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, transpose

I'm doing the select:

```
select  id,
        status,
        count(status) as qtd
from    user
group by id, status;
```

The return is:

```
id | status | qtd
1     YES      5
1      NO      3
2     YES      3
2      NO      1
```

I want this:

```
id | YES | NO
1     5    3
2     3    1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## NOTE:

you can use case logic to do what you want.. basically you want to pivot the results and to pivot them you have to use aggregates with conditionals to fake a pivot table since mysql doesn't have a way to accomplish that

## QUERY:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    SUM(CASE status WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'YES',
    SUM(CASE status WHEN 'No'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'NO'
FROM user
GROUP BY id;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60f3c/1)

## OUTPUT:

```
+----+-----+----+
| id | YES | NO |
+----+-----+----+
| 1  |  5  | 3  |
| 2  |  3  | 1  |
+----+-----+----+
```

Comment: @OsvaldoBergJunior if you could please chose an answer and mark it as accepted it would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do so,using expression in sum() like `sum(status ='Yes')` will result as boolean (0/1) and thus you can have your count based on your criteria you provide in sum function

```
select id,
 sum(status ='Yes') as `YES`,
 sum(status ='No') as `NO`
 from user
group by id;
```

Comment: very nice! using the boolean result is a pretty cool way to do it.. but I believe you shouldn't group by status.. just by the ID to get a good pivoted result :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell I just copied the grouping criteria of OP didn't realize that thanks for the correction

Comment: I did the same thing! and then realized it a little later :) +1 for another way to do it :)